# Appdynamics vs Crittercism which one should be used for crash logs and health check for iOS/Android apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, crittercism, appdynamics

Is this comparison even valid? 
Appdynamics does a lot of other things beyond crash logs. So using Crittercism for crashlogs is a good idea or bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both products essentially do the same thing, if anything AppDynamics has advanced beyond Crittercism (now called Apteligent). They had the lead when the mAPM market started, but now there is not much innovating happening, especially after they sold the company to VMware earlier this year.

Here are the mRUM docs for AppD: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO44/Mobile+Real+User+Monitoring some of the more advanced features in AppD you will not find in Appteligent would be things like screen recording, breadcrumb/navigation for every click and interaction. The most valuable feature, of course, is the measurement outside of a straight mobile use case. AppD does measure and ties together the mobile transaction with the backend, server (and network), Docker containers, AWS or other cloud providers. Additionally, it monitors performance and usage of browsers.

Disclosure: I used to be the lead for these products at Gartner, and have been working at AppDynamics for the last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

For Apple platforms I recommend you to avoid any third party crash log frameworks and use [Xcode crashes organizer.](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev861f46ea8)

- Your app can be smaller and faster
- There's no setup
- You will be able to see what line of code caused crash
- Better privacy for your users as it's opt-in
- It's free

Answer (score -2):

It's actually more the other way around - Crittercism does crash logging, network monitoring, and performance timing whereas AppDynamics is more focused on server monitoring.

Comment: Thanks. So AppDynamics does not do any crash logging for iOS/Android apps.